# Moment.js Plugins should I install both dependencies?

Tags: javascript, node.js, date, npm, momentjs

I want to use a moment.js plugin like [moment-business-days](https://www.npmjs.com/package/moment-business-days).
Should I install both dependencies?

```
npm install moment-business-days
npm install moment // yes / no / maybe?
```

Or is it enough to install the plugin as it comes with the moment.js dependency itself?

Is there a best practice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends, if you would like to use it in the browser, you have to include both in your HTML file.

```html
<!-- Browser -->
<!-- NB: add after moment.js -->
<script src="moment.js"></script>
<script src="moment-business-days.js"></script>
```

When using it in Node.js you have to install only one `moment-business-days`

```
const moment = require('moment-business-days');
```

It will automatically include `moment` for you:
https://github.com/kalmecak/moment-business-days/blob/master/index.js#L4

It also has a peerDependency to `moment`:
https://github.com/kalmecak/moment-business-days/blob/master/package.json#L23

Answer (score 2):

`moment.js`Dependencies:

> `benchmark`,`coveralls`,`es6-promise`,`grunt`,`grunt-benchmark`,`grunt-cli`,`grunt-contrib-clean`,`grunt-contrib-concat`,`grunt-contrib-copy`,`grunt-contrib-jshint`,`grunt-contrib-uglify`,`grunt-contrib-watch`,`grunt-env`,`grunt-exec`,`grunt-jscs`,`grunt-karma`,`grunt-nuget`,`grunt-string-replace`,`karma`,`karma-chrome-launcher`,`karma-firefox-launcher`,`karma-qunit`,`karma-sauce-launcher`,`load-grunt-tasks`,`node-qunit`,`nyc`,`qunit`,`rollup`,`spacejam`,`typescript`,`uglify-js`

`moment-business`
This is a Moment.js library that allows Moment operations for Western work weeks: 7 day weeks where Saturday and Sunday are non-work days.

So you need to install both.

See this [doc](http://momentjs.com/docs/)